# Go to a specific URL after command button click

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm using a script and windows.open function to go to a specific URL when a user click a button on the VFpage. Something is going wrong because after the click the same page is reloaded.

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function goback()
 {
   window.open(retURL);
 }
</script>
```

Inside the retURL variable, there is the URL where I want to go, something like:
https://eu6.salesforce.com/0015800000DuQWsAAN'

button:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!deleteContract}" value="Elimina Contratto e prodotti selezionati" immediate="true"  onclick= "goback()" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try window.location.href =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using controller then better to navigate from the controller method. Do not use javascript for this.

In the last line of the method write like this:

```
return (new ApexPages.StandardController (new SObject(Id='0015800000DuQWsAAN'))).view();
```

replace the SObject with the name of specific object for which your recordId is `'0015800000DuQWsAAN'`